# ASP.NET membership spaces in username

Tags: asp.net, spaces, membership

We just came across a weird bug in our application that uses the asp.net membership.

The administrator had created some users with spaces behind their name: 'My Username     '
In the Users table this is saved normally, so without the spaces: 'My Username'
The user can also login using the name without the spaces: 'My Username'
When we use User.Identity.Name in our applicatie the result is the username WITH the spaces: 'My Username     '.

Where do these spaces come from? They aren't stored in the Users table so where does he get this from?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How are you determining that it isn't stored in the DB *with* the space at the end? Are you sure the SSMS isn't just hiding it from you?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I see these spaces in our own tables when I edit the field, but not when I do this in the users table.

Comment: This is almost guaranteed.  The spaces are in the DB, you just can't see them. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316626

Comment: @SaphuA: What is the type of the field in your own tables?